# LuaTeX/TeX-core: Where is my display math? (sequence of execution, display math insertion, etc)

Tags: math-mode, luatex, amsmath, tex-core, displaystyle

***This is a LuaTeX/TeX-core internal node representation question, not a question concerned with output in PDF.***

While trying to visualize the contents of paragraphs, "display math" contents are missing. I tried both pre_linebreak, and post_linebreak filter. Why is that so? What is the sequence of execution? How does TeX/LuaTeX keep track of insertion points of display math, where does it temporarily store it? and how/when does it insert it back into the final nodelist? This same behavior does not occur for "inline math" (its contents are visible in both pre, and post linebreak phase).

In my example below, paragraph-2 has some regular text "Par2", some "inline math" ($x=d^3$), and some "display math" (in align* environment).

Output:
[image: Screenshot from output pdf]

Code:

```latex
% >> lualatex missingmlist.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\directlua{
    nodetree = require"nodetree"
    function filterprint(h)
        nodetree.print(h)
        return h
    end
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",filterprint,"filterprint")
}

\begin{document}

Par1

Par2 $x=d^3$\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2 &= z^2\\
a^2+b^2+1 &= c^3
\end{align*}

Par3

\end{document}
```

Console (look at contents of 2nd paragraph, display math nodes are missing):

```
├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent, width: 15pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: P, width: 6.81pt, height: 6.83pt
├─KERN kern: -0.28pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: a, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
│   properties: {['injections'] = {['leftkern'] = -18350.08}}
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: r, width: 3.92pt, height: 4.42pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: 1, width: 5pt, height: 6.66pt
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil

├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent, width: 15pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: P, width: 6.81pt, height: 6.83pt
├─KERN kern: -0.28pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: a, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
│   properties: {['injections'] = {['leftkern'] = -18350.08}}
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: r, width: 3.92pt, height: 4.42pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: 2, width: 5pt, height: 6.66pt
├─GLUE subtype: spaceskip, width: 3.33pt, stretch: 1.66pt, shrink: 1.11pt
├─MATH 
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: , width: 5.72pt, height: 4.42pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─GLUE subtype: thickmuskip, width: 2.78pt, stretch: 2.78pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: =, width: 7.78pt, height: 3.67pt
├─PENALTY subtype: noadpenalty, penalty: 500
├─GLUE subtype: thickmuskip, width: 2.78pt, stretch: 2.78pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: , width: 5.2pt, height: 6.94pt, depth: 0.11pt
├─KERN subtype: italiccorrection, kern: 0.24pt
├─HLIST subtype: sup, width: 4.54pt, depth: 0.14pt, height: 4.65pt, shift: -3.63pt
│ ╚═head:
│   └─GLYPH char: 3, width: 3.98pt, height: 4.65pt, depth: 0.14pt
├─MATH subtype: endmath
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil

├─LOCAL_PAR 
├─HLIST subtype: indent, width: 15pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: P, width: 6.81pt, height: 6.83pt
├─KERN kern: -0.28pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: a, width: 5pt, height: 4.48pt, depth: 0.11pt
│ ╚═  properties: {['injections'] = {['leftkern'] = -18350.08}}
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: r, width: 3.92pt, height: 4.42pt
├─GLYPH subtype: 256, char: 3, width: 5pt, height: 6.66pt, depth: 0.22pt
├─PENALTY subtype: linepenalty, penalty: 10000
└─GLUE subtype: parfillskip, stretch: +1fil
```

Comment: display math does not take part in linebreaking

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes it might not, but its "nodes" must be sitting somewhere right? Given `\showoutput` shows those nodes, the display nodes must get inserted somewhere in the final node list. Lets take for example pre linebreak phase... My question is where are they, how can I access them during pre-linebreak phase, and how can I know what the mapping/insertion point is in the pre_linebreak_filter node list.

Comment: the inputs to the pre_linebreak filter are the partial paragraphs that take part in linebreaking _between_ displays and the input to post_linebreak filter are the lines resulting from linebreaking those partial paragraphs. So a single logical paragraph with a math display looks to these filters like two separate paragraphs, they will be called twice, for the text above and below the display. You willl not see the math just as you do not see and vertical glue nodes added between paragraphs by `\vspace` etc/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The math display is converted to a vlist of hboxes and added directly to the main vertical list so not seen by the linebreaking callbacks. You can for example use the `vpack_filter` to see the math nodes being added to the main vertical list (and the tabskip from the align)

```
   │   │   ├─GLUE subtype: tabskip
    │   │   ├─HLIST subtype: cell, width: 22.83pt, depth: 3.6pt, height: 8.4pt
    │   │   │ ╚═head:
    │   │   │   ├─HLIST subtype: box, width: 22.46pt, depth: 0.11pt, height: 8.28pt
    │   │   │   │ ╚═head:
    │   │   │   │   ├─MATH 
    │   │   │   │   ├─HLIST width: 22.46pt, depth: 0.11pt, height: 8.28pt
    │   │   │   │   │ ╚═head:
    │   │   │   │   │   ├─HLIST 
    │   │   │   │   │   ├─GLUE subtype: thickmuskip, width: 2.78pt, stretch: 2.78pt
    │   │   │   │   │   ├─GLYPH char: =, width: 7.78pt, height: 3.67pt
    │   │   │   │   │   ├─GLUE subtype: thickmuskip, width: 2.78pt, stretch: 2.78pt
    │   │   │   │   │   ├─GLYPH char: , width: 4.33pt, height: 4.42pt, depth: 0.11pt
    │   │   │   │   │   ├─KERN subtype: italiccorrection, kern: 0.25pt
    │   │   │   │   │   └─HLIST subtype: sup, width: 4.54pt, depth: 0.14pt, height: 4.65pt, shift: -3.63pt
    │   │   │   │   │     ╚═head:
    │   │   │   │   │       └─GLYPH char: 3, width: 3.98pt, height: 4.65pt, depth: 0.14pt
    │   │   │   │   └─MATH subtype: endmath
    │   │   │   └─GLUE stretch: +1fil
    │   │   ├─GLUE subtype: tabskip, width: 136.96pt
```

Comment: Thanks, when I use vpack filter, it prints the same list 3 times... Is there a way to make it just print what is being added to main vertical list? I would guess it does the other prints for material that eventually gets discarded, though there is no way to know (for me at least)

Comment: @reportaman it really depends what you are doing, and why. the vpack filter is called whenever something is replaced in a vertical list so the same nodes can appear multiple times, if you want something more like `\showoutput` that just shows the nodes that are shipped out you could use pre_output_filter or in fact not use a callback at all and just hook into the normal tex output routine and insert a lua print function that iterates over box 255

Comment: Yeah, `pre_output_filter` won't help. Am playing with nodelists to capture contents of a `\vbox` and post-process in funky ways (inspired from author of [chickenize](https://ctan.org/pkg/chickenize?lang=en)) to learn how TeX works. With pre/post linebreak filter I can get contents of paragraphs cleanly, but so far there is no way to get list being added to the `\vbox`'s outermost vertical list by display math. Is there a way to call something like `append_to_vlist_filter` but only such that it is triggered/called/does something when contents are added to outermost list inside a `\vbox`?

Comment: @reportaman mlist_to_hlist (and checking for displaytype being display?

Comment: Just tried, that too doesn't help for 2 reasons: 1) It gets called twice for all contents (which could be solvable), and more importantly 2) Its not what I am looking for as it doesn't really give me head of the nested list that ultimately gets added because of this align environment in the question. All of the glues, and tabskip, etc are absent.

Comment: the twice is because align sets is content twice, if you are adjusting things in the callback you probably need to adjust both runs as the first run is a "measuring pass" that is used to help with the alignment, so if you move nodes around in the second pass but not the first you would most likely break the amsmath logic.